# Slicing list with different string matching conditions

Tags: python, indexing, list-comprehension, slice

I'd like to slice a list of strings based on substrings *possibly* contained into its elements:

```
l = ['Some long text', 'often begins', ' with ',
     'impenetrable fog ', 'which ends', ' somewhere further']
startIndex = [u for u, v in enumerate(l) if 'begins' in v)][0]
finalIndex = [u for u, v in enumerate(l) if 'ends' in v)][0]
```

so that I'd get:

```
' '.join(l[startIndex:finalIndex]) == 'often begins with impenetrable fog'
```

My main problem being that the beginning and end conditions used to get indexes are different and should be variable (basic substring containment as above-mentioned, regexes or other methods possible).

First and last elements might need to be stripped out but I guess this is a matter of adjusting indexes by 1.
My code works in the ideal cases but will often fail as structure and contents of `l` are not very predictable. Absence of one or both elements matching conditions should end up with the final string being `None`.

Are comprehensions relevant, or mapping a lambda function to apply both conditions?

Comment: Can you please provide the clear example? Do you want all the `strings` in `list` between the `start` and `end` string. For example: `['How May', 'I help', 'You with', 'Your Problem', 'Andreas']`.  With start = `help`, and end = `Problem`. What should be your required output?

Comment: Yes I'd like to get `'You with Your Problem'` as output with your example. Thanks for replying anyway!

Comment: By the way, what did you already try with map and lambda functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
l = ['Some long text', 'often begins', 'with', 'impenetrable fog', 'which ends', 'somewhere further']

"""
return the index of the phase in 'phases' if phase contains 'word'
if not found, return 'default'
"""
def index(phases, word, default):
    for i, s in enumerate(phases):
        if word in s: return i
    return default

startIndex = index(l, "long", -1)
finalIndex = index(l, "somewhere", len(l))

print(' '.join(l[startIndex+1:finalIndex]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
l = ['Some long text', 'often begins', ' with ', 'impenetrable fog ', 
     'which   ends', ' somewhere further']

startIndex = next((u for u, v in enumerate(l) if 'begins' in v), 0)
finalIndex = next((u for u, v in enumerate(l) if 'ends' in v), 0)

if (startIndex and finalIndex) and (finalIndex > startIndex):
    sentence = ' '.join(l[startIndex:finalIndex])
else:
    sentence = None
print(sentence)
```

Similar as list comprehension, execpt it doesn't return a list but the first element it found. if it doesn't found anything, it return an optional element (here `'0'`)

This way, if there is no `'begins'` or no `'ends'` in your list, you don't have to print anything. Therefore, this allows you to check either if the `'ends'` comes before the `'begins'`.

I also love list comprehension but sometimes what you need isn't a list.

**SOLUTION FOR ADVANCE USER:**

The problem with the use of two comprehension list, is that you check twice your list from start and it will fail when `ends` comes before start:

```
l = ['Some long text ends here',  'often begins', ' with ', 'which   ends']
                     ^^^
```

To avoid this, you might use a generator with [`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#examples) to only iterate once on your list.

```
def get_index(trigger_word):
    for u, v in enumerate(l):
        if trigger_word in v:
            trigger_word = yield u

gen = get_index('begins')
startIndex = gen.send(None)
finalIndex = gen.send('ends')
```

Here, the `yield` allows you to get the index without exiting the function.

This is better, but if there is no `begins` or `ends`in the list, there will be a [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) exception. To avoid this, you can just do a infinite loop on `yield` 0 instead. Now the complete solution will be:

```
def get_index(l, trigger_word):
    for u, v in enumerate(l):
        if trigger_word in v:
            trigger_word = yield u
    while True:
        yield 0

def concat_with_trigger_words(l):           
    gen = get_index(l, 'begins')
    startIndex = gen.send(None)
    finalIndex = gen.send('ends')
    return ' '.join(l[startIndex:finalIndex]) if (startIndex and finalIndex) else None

# Here some list for free lists for your future unitary tests ;)

l_orignal = ['Some long text here',  'often begins', ' with ', 
             'impenetrable fog ', 'which   ends', ' somewhere further']
l_start_with_ends = ['ends',  'often begins', ' with ', 
                     'impenetrable fog ', 'which   ends', 'begins']
l_none = ['random', 'word']
l_without_begin = ['fog', 'ends here']
l_without_end = ['begins', 'but never' '...']

print(concat_with_trigger_words(l_orignal)) # often begins  with  impenetrable fog 
print(concat_with_trigger_words(l_start_with_ends)) # often begins  with  impenetrable fog 
print(concat_with_trigger_words(l_none)) # None
print(concat_with_trigger_words(l_without_end)) # None
print(concat_with_trigger_words(l_without_begin)) # None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['Some long text', 'often begins', ' with ',
...      'impenetrable fog ', 'which ends', ' somewhere further']
>>> start, end = 'begins', 'ends'
>>> key_index = {'start': {'word': start, 'index': -1}, 
                 'end': {'word': end, 'index': -1}}
>>> for i, val in enumerate(l):
...     if key_index['start']['word'] in val:
...         key_index['start']['index'] = i
...     elif key_index['end']['word'] in val:
...         key_index['end']['index'] = i
...
>>> start_index, end_index = key_index['start']['index'], key_index['end']['index']
>>> my_list = l[start_index+1:end_index] if start_index >=0 and end_index >= 0 and start_index+1 < end_index else None
>>> my_list
[' with ', 'impenetrable fog ']
```